# Why in Microsoft Access i cant add zero in the begging of the phone number field?

Tags: database, ms-access

I was trying to add a phone number that started with 0 once i click enter the 0 get removed ?!
in the field properties i chooses (Number) i changed it in to decimal then integer..etc still 
the 0 get removed?!

[image: that the DB view design]

Comment: I meant in the beginning of the field  ☺

Comment: I would advise using a Short Text field to store a phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers don't have leading zeros. If you want to save a leading zero, you should use a textual type like `varchar`.

Comment: where can i put that varchar?

Comment: Go to table design. _Short Text_ it is.